# Installing ubuntu packages within python script

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python3

I want to install following packages within my python script :

```
python-pip python-sqlalchemy mongodb python-bson python-dpkt python-jinja2 
python-magic python-gridfs python-libvirt python-bottle python-pefile
python-chardet git build-essential autoconf automake libtool dh-autoreconf 
libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmagic-dev python-dev tcpdump libcap2-bin virtualbox 
dkms python-pyrex
```

I have written the following code but it is not working. How can I solve this problem?

```
    self.command = "apt install"
    self.packages = "python-pip python-sqlalchemy mongodb python-bson python-dpkt python-jinja2 python-magic python-gridfs python-libvirt python-bottle python-pefile python-chardet git build-essential autoconf automake libtool dh-autoreconf libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmagic-dev python-dev tcpdump libcap2-bin virtualbox dkms python-pyrex"

    print("[+] Installation of the ubuntu packages is starting:")
    for items in packages:
        subprocess.run(str(command.split()) + str(items), stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
        print("\[+] Package {} Installed".format(str(self.items)))
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages or what exactly happens when you run this?

Comment: I think the problem is `str(command.split()) + str(items)`. If you change that to `command.split() + [items]` it should probably work...

Comment: @ByteCommander I do that but Exception Occured : can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Did you forget the square brackets around `[items]`?

Comment: You are missing `self.` in `for items in packages:`  Should have been `for items in self.packages:`

Comment: Also, you might want to check if packages actually installed. You are redirecting everything to dev null, so user won't see any error. You might wanna do `subprocess.check_call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues there:

- You are missing `self` in `for items in packages:`
- `self.packages` is a string, when you call `for item self.packages` it iterates over each character of that string. You should have declared packages as list from the beginning or added `.split()` at the end.
- your `self.packages` is long, doesn't conform to PEP8 standard of 79 characters per line.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed :

```
def package_installation(self):
    self.apt = "apt "
    self.ins = "install "
    self.packages = "python-pip python-sqlalchemy mongodb python-bson python-dpkt python-jinja2 python-magic python-gridfs python-libvirt python-bottle python-pefile python-chardet git build-essential autoconf automake libtool dh-autoreconf libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmagic-dev python-dev tcpdump libcap2-bin virtualbox dkms python-pyrex"

    self.color.print_green("[+] Installation of the ubuntu packages is starting:")

    for self.items in self.packages.split():
        self.command = str(self.apt) + str(self.ins) + str(self.items)

        subprocess.run(self.command.split())
        self.color.print_blue("\t[+] Package [{}] Installed".format(str(self.items)))
```